# download file directly from http server

Tags: linux, browser

I would like to download a large file(s)  from a web server given `x.x.x.x:80`

Usually `wget` and/or `curl` would suffice but I do not  have a directory/to/file.zip to download, all I have is an IP.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the name of the file, you can only access whatever is visible at that IP address and port.  If there is a webpage with links & dependencies, `wget` can do a recursive get on anything  linked.  If you're trying to access something not made visible, you must know the file name. It's a server-side restriction.